Format Logs of .fit() in Tensorflow
When fitting my tensorflow (2.15) model, I get the following logs:
Epoch 2/10
32/32 - 0s - loss: 17.3287 - 99ms/epoch - 3ms/step
Epoch 3/10
32/32 - 0s - loss: 16.9345 - 123ms/epoch - 4ms/step

and so on... I want to add a timestamp to the "logging" message (I dont think this is logging, since changing the logger format did not change anything in the messages for me). Anyway, I thought I could just use a on_epoch_end callback and create my own logging message. But with that I cannot access the runtime information like the ms/step metric.
What I am asking: Can I add a time to the messages of fit? If not, where would I find the training time per epoch in an on_epoch_end callback?
import logging
import sys

import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# logging setup
logger = tf.get_logger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)


class LoggerTensorflow(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        epoch_string = f"Epoch {epoch + 1} / {self.params['epochs']}"
        logs_formatted = " - ".join([f"{k}: {v:.4f}" for k, v in logs.items()])
        logger.info(f"{epoch_string} - {logs_formatted}")
        return super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)


# Generate some fake data: 1000 samples with 1 feature.
np.random.seed(42)  # for reproducible results
x_data = np.random.rand(1000, 1)  # features
y_data = 3 * x_data + 2 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, (1000, 1))  # targets with noise


# Build a simple linear regression model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))])

# Compile the model specifying the optimizer, loss function, and metrics to track
model.compile(loss="mse")

# Train the model
model.fit(x_data, y_data, epochs=10, verbose=2)


what do u mean 'add a timestamp to the "logging" message'? What's wrong with 0s - loss: 17.3287 - 99ms/epoch - 3ms/step?

@Innat I want to know at what time that epoch was finished. Something like `04.06.2024, 8:09: Epoch 2/10 32/32 - 0s - loss: 17.3287 - 99ms/epoch - 3ms/step. Otherwise it is fairly difficult to know when the last epoch was finished (when running on a virtual machine and long epoch training times). For me it happened that the training stopped, but I couldn't know because I didn't know when the last epoch stopped. Hence I want to add a time to the logs but then I am not finding the ms/step metrics when using the callback for my own log message

I couldn't find a way to alter the logs from .fit() which seem to be print messages instead of logging messages. The way to got is probably an own callback. That is what I have implemented (if it helps anyone):

class LoggerTensorflow(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, verbose: Literal[0, 1, 2] = 1):
        """Logging the training progress of a tensorflow model.

        Args:
            verbose (Literal[0, 1, 2], optional): 0 is no logging, 1 logs to the console and 2 uses the root logger settings. Defaults to 1.
        """
        super().__init__()

        self.start_time = None  # time at the beginning of the epoch

        # setup logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("tenforflow-fit")
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        if verbose == 0:  # no logging
            self.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        elif verbose == 1:  # logging but not using the root logger
            self.logger.propagate = False
            # Create and add console handler
            console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            # add formatter
            formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
            console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

            self.logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # set time
        self.start_time = time.time()
        return super().on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # compute duration
        duration = time.time() - self.start_time
        general_info = f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{self.params['epochs']} - {duration:.3f}s"  # epoch number and time
        loss = ""  # string to hold the losses
        for k, v in logs.items():
            k = k.replace("output_", "")
            if k != "val_loss":
                k = k.replace("_loss", "")

            # add to string
            loss += f"{k} {v:.4f} - "

        self.logger.info(general_info + ": " + loss)
        return super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

